# What hook to be used for updating stock after payment in WooCommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I am using my own payment method in javascript code, I got the total amount correctly and pass it successfully to my payment by using :

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['cart_total']  = WC()->cart->total;  
$cart_total = WC()->cart->total;    
?>
```

In a javascript function, if my payment is successful, then it redirects customer to an Url…

My question is: What is the code that is responsible to update my inventory after making the payment?

This is the callback function :

```
function completeCallback(response) {
    console.log("completeCallback", response);
    resultIndicator = response;
    var result = (resultIndicator === successIndicator) ? "SUCCESS" : "ERROR";
    window.location.href="https://www.example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `do_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', $order_id )` hook